# create variable with case_when/if_any across multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I have a dataset with names from some variables corresponding to each month (e.g. var1_M1, var1_M2 var2_M1 ...) and I need to summarize by each month (after conditional) and identify the first case when I find a value > 90 and finally indicate the corresponding month.

```
library(dplyr)

ID <- c("Dave", "Joe", "Steve")
var1_M1 <- c(10, 10, 90)
var1_M2 <- c(30, 90, 95)
var1_M3 <- c(90, 100, 95)
var2_M1 <- c(10, 90, 20)
var2_M2 <- c(33, 10, 100)
var2_M3 <- c(90, 10, 50)

data <- tibble(ID, var1_M1, var1_M2, var1_M3, var2_M1, var2_M2, var2_M3)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  ID    var1_M1 var1_M2 var1_M3 var2_M1 var2_M2 var2_M3
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Dave       10      30      90      10      33      90
2 Joe        10      90     100      90      10      10
3 Steve      90      95      95      20     100      50

data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches(c("M1","M2","M3"))),
            list(~ ifelse(. > 90, .,0))) #%>% 
  #mutate() using map_dfc and if_any ??
```

#### Expected output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  ID       M1    M2    M3 output
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Dave      0     0     0      0
2 Joe       0     0   100      3
3 Steve     0   195    95      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, grouped by 'ID', get the `sum` `across` the columns, where the value is greater than 90, and create the `output` of the first column index value not 0 with `max.col`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(data, cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value"), 
   names_pattern = ".*_(.*)") %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x[.x > 90]))) %>% 
   mutate(output = max.col(across(starts_with("M")) >0, "first") * 
     if_any(starts_with("M"), ~ .x > 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  ID       M1    M2    M3 output
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1 Dave      0     0     0      0
2 Joe       0     0   100      3
3 Steve     0   195    95      2
```

With `pivot_longer`, we specified a regex in `names_pattern` to capture the characters after the `_` as a group (`(...)`) in column names i.e. `M1`, `M2`, `M3`) using `.*` - to match zero or more characters, and specify the `names_to` as `.value` so that it reshape to long format with the column names as `M1`, `M2`, `M3` combining all the `var_` columns.

After we `summarise` with the `sum`, use `max.col` to find the first index of column values greater than 0.  In the first row, i.e. for Dave id, all the values are 0, thus `max.col` returns the index 1.  In order to make it 0, multiply with TRUE/FALSE output from `if_any` (`TRUE` -> 1, `FALSE` -> 0). i.e. it may be better to create a column to understand it better

```
pivot_longer(data, cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value"), 
   names_pattern = ".*_(.*)") %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x[.x > 90]))) %>%
   mutate(if_any_ind = if_any(starts_with("M"), ~ .x > 0),
           output_ind =max.col(across(starts_with("M")) >0, "first"),
           output = if_any_ind * output_ind)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  ID       M1    M2    M3 if_any_ind output_ind output
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>           <int>  <int>
1 Dave      0     0     0 FALSE               1      0
2 Joe       0     0   100 TRUE                3      3
3 Steve     0   195    95 TRUE                2      2
```

ie. any value x 0 -> 0 and value x 1 -> 1

Comment: ty so much akrun :D can u explain me pls how to use `pivot_longer(names_pattern = ".*_(.*)")` and `max.col()*if_any()`?

Comment: yeah, it works! :D So, I'd like to know how `max.col()*if_any()` works